# как вывести элемент multimap?

Tags: c++, словари, unicode

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::multimap<char*, char> mp;
    mp.insert("00", "\u28FF");
    printf("%s\n", mp["00"]);
    return 0;
}
```

Стоит задача сделать таблицу символов юникода в памяти, и обращаться по номеру элемента к её частям (00, 01, FF, и т д). Вставка элементов работает. А вот вывести элемент - выдаёт ошибку компиляции. Да и вообще, как грамотно обратиться к элементу словаря по одному из ключей.

Использование std::map выдаёт ошибку:

```
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/c++/v1/map:1199:17: error:                      no matching member function for call to 'insert'
                insert(__e.__i_, *__f);
                ^~~~~~
test.cpp:6:8: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::map<char *, char>::insert<const char *>' requested here
    mp.insert("00", "\u28FF");
```

Нашёл вариант `mp.insert(std::pair("00", "\u28FF"));`. Ошибка:

```
test.cpp:6:8: error: no matching member function for call to
      'insert'                                                                        mp.insert(std::make_pair("00", "\u28FF"));
    ~~~^~~~~~
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/c++/v1/map:1173:9: note:
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'pair<typename
      __unwrap_ref_decay<const char (&)[3]>::type, typename
      __unwrap_ref_decay<const char (&)[4]>::type>' to 'const pair<const
      std::map<char *, char>::key_type, std::map<char *, char>::mapped_type>'
      for 1st argument
        insert(const value_type& __v) {return __tree_.__insert_unique(__v);}
        ^
```

Comment: *"Вставка элементов работает."* - а вот и нет. Тут явно подразумевается вставка одного элемента, однако типы объектов, передаваемых в `insert` не соответсвуют перегрузке для вставки одного элемента.

Comment: Мне просто надо сделать словарь из пары "число / символ юникода"...

Comment: У вас 1. нет числа, 2. нет символа, 3. зачем-то использован `multimap` — у вас одному "числу" может соответствовать несколько "символов"? Используя `char*`, вы записываете *адреса* конкретных строк, и нет гарантии, что все одинаковые строки компилятор будет размещать по одному адресу, и уж точно этот адрес не совпадет с адресом динамической строки времени выполнения... Но вопрос вы задали, конечно же, не как решить вашу задачу, а как вывести элемент. Которого - ОДНОГО - нет, на то и "мульти"...

Comment: Ну, число я могу записать и как символ char*. Просто, я не хочу, чтобы при обращении по числу происходило обращение по индексу массива, потому и делаю "00" а не 0. (А там ещё я хочу сделать FF, AB - т е тут уже реальные символы, а не числа). С map у меня вообще даже не компилируется, жёстко ругается на тип данных. Ах да, \u28FF - символ юникода, проверьте через гугл или `echo -ne` в вашей Linux/Unix консоли

Comment: Мда, крепко запущено... Зачем мне лезть в Google, если `""` — указатель на массив символов, пусть даже и из одного символа, но никак не символ сам по себе. Примерно то же самое относится и к остальному. `"00"` — это массив символов, но никак не число. С `map` не компилируется — вообще аргументация железная. Почему тогда `multimap`, а не `float`? Все равно же не работает, но разбираться, *почему* — не наш же метод, наш метод — тыкать что угодно в надежде, что а вдруг заработает... Кстати, для `multimap` — и я уже намекал — оператор `[]` не определен, нет там ОДНОГО значения...

Comment: Кинул ошибку с std:map

Comment: И да, как тогда в этом вашем map обращаться к элементам по одному ключу..

Comment: Я бы поставил закрытие за то, что автор похоже сам не понимает что хочет, но не могу. Поэтому поставлю минус.

Comment: Бляяять. Извините за мат, но я так не могу. Я чётко сказал, что мне надо создать пару "число в char/string - символ юникода". Сказал, что мне надо как-то обращаться к элементам словаря.

Comment: И только в комментариях мистер Harry смог выяснить, что вам нужно иметь несколько ключей для элемента ... О чём ещё можно говорить? Я думаю, если вы опишите правильно то, что хотите, то я уберу минус и вам смогут нормально тут помочь

Comment: И кстати, компилятор вам ясно даёт понять, что вы НЕ МОЖЕТЕ `char*` положить в место, которое предназначено для `char`. Поэтому он не может сгенерировать метод `insert`. То, что у вас является символом юникода не делает его типом `char`.

Comment: Чего? И как мне тогда с символами юникода работать? Что же это за чертовщина, что единичный символ - в данном случае символ шрифта Брайля - читается как некое множество символов? А с другой стороны - спасибо, что сказали, использование `std::string` в моём случае сработало.

Comment: Советую почитать [вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61977664/how-to-use-utf-8-and-unicode-in-c-how-big-is-c20-char8-t) и все вопросы отпадут сами собой.